# jQuery how show div over overflow hidden box

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using simple jcarousel here is ther code: http://jsfiddle.net/w6fLA/

I'm trying to show div box with txt when hover "li" but overflow hidden hides the element how can I show box top of everything?

here is my js:

```
$('.jcarousel-skin-tango li').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).append($("<div class='box'><p>" + $(this).find('img').attr('alt') + "</p></div>").hide().fadeIn(300));
    },

    function(){
        $('.box').fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove();});
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still needs some finessing, but instead of appending the tooltip to the inner element, apply it to the body instead. Then position it using the `offset` top and left properties of the image jQuery object. I changed some of the CSS too.

http://jsfiddle.net/w6fLA/1/

```
$('.jcarousel-skin-tango li').hover(
    function(){
        var $img = $(this).find('img');
        $('body')
            .append($("<div class='box'><p>" + $img
            .attr('alt') + "</p></div>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(300)
            .css('top', $img.offset().top + 60)
            .css('left', $img.offset().left + 30));
    },

    function(){
        $('.box').fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove();});
    }
);
​
```

Answer (score 1):

The way the carousel is implemented prevents you to do it by inserting the tooltip inside.

An option would be inserting the level at  level as a "position:absolute", and control its position with the mouse coordinates.